# Why is "if[ i %2==0]" always true?

Tags: python

Need support/please clear my doubt:

```
def test(strValue):
    for i in range(len(strValue)):
        if[ i %2==0]:
            strValue.replace(strValue[i] ,strValue[i].upper())
            print('if loop '+strValue)
        else:
            strValue.replace(strValue[i] ,strValue[i].lower())
            print('else loop '+strValue)
**input:**
 test('apple')
**output:**
if loop apple
if loop apple
if loop apple
if loop apple
if loop apple
```

1.why if[ i %2==0] is always true
2.why strValue is not changed

Comment: what is the value of `strValue`?

Comment: `[ i %2==0]` is equal to either `[True]` or `[False]` depending on the value of `i`, so is a non empty list, which is truthy.

Comment: `str.replace` does not modify the string in-place, it returns the modified value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python, when to use a square or round brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46675477/188256)

Comment: You probably want `if i%2 == 0:` i.e. without backets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- `[i%2==0]` is a list of one element being the result of your test. In python, the brackets build a list. So you should just remove the bracket and your test will be fine.

2- `strValue.replace(strValue[i] ,strValue[i].lower())` is not in-place modification. Strings are immutable in python so you need to store the result of this call in strValue and hence erase the former value.

So the working code in your case is:

```
def test(strValue):
    for i in range(len(strValue)):
        if i %2==0:
            strValue = strValue.replace(strValue[i] ,strValue[i].upper())
            print('if loop '+strValue)
        else:
            strValue = strValue.replace(strValue[i] ,strValue[i].lower())
            print('else loop '+strValue)
```

Comment: thanks .code works but 
**input:**
 test('apple')

**output:**

if loop Apple
else loop Apple
if loop APPle
else loop APPle
if loop APPlE

-- In 3 rd line output is "if loop APPle"  
i am not clear why both p changed to P

Answer (score 0):

To answer your problems

1. The value of `[i%2==0]` is not always equal to `True`, it is either [`True]` or `[False]` depending on the `i` value but the non-empty list like `[True]` or `[False]` is always `True` so try to do this way

   `i%2==0` instead of `[i%2==0]`
2. You're replacing the `strValue` but not assigning it back. So do this way-

   strValue = strValue.replace(strValue[i] ,strValue[i].upper())

**DEMO & EXPLANATION:** https://rextester.com/AHJHS98230

Comment: The main issue is not that. The OP is using a list as the condition for if

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes, sir I agreed with you. The main issue not only the list condition but also on string replace. I was editing my answer but in the meantime you downvoted. :)

Comment: Okay sir, now that your answer is complete, I take back my downvote ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Thank you sir :) Happy coding!