# What does it mean to surround an integer with square brackets in a bytes() call in python?

Tags: python, types

Say you write `bytes(10)`, from my understanding, this will create a byte array with 10 bytes; however if you were to instead write `bytes([10])` you would get the binary value of 10.

What effect do square brackets have on the datatype of a number? I cannot find any information on them as an operator.

Comment: It has nothing to do with numbers in particular, that's how you construct a list.  `["hello"]` would likewise be a list containing a single string.

Comment: It will be considered as list
you can check with `type([9])`
output will be `<class 'list'>`

Comment: "I cannot find any information on them as an operator." I got to the linked duplicate by putting `square brackets python` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=square+brackets+python), checking the first link (which was to a Stack Overflow question) and following to the duplicate of [*that* one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675477/in-python-when-to-use-a-square-or-round-brackets). The reason you won't find square brackets on a list of Python operators is the same reason you won't find double or single quotes - it's part of a *literal syntax*.

Comment: Also, as @MrBhuyan indicates, Python has type introspection built in, so that's the first place to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[10]` is a list literal. It creates a list with a single element, and that element is 10.

`bytes()` behaves in several different ways depending on the argument, as you can see from its `help()` documentation:

```
class bytes(object)
 |  bytes(iterable_of_ints) -> bytes
 |  bytes(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytes
 |  bytes(bytes_or_buffer) -> immutable copy of bytes_or_buffer
 |  bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes
 |  bytes() -> empty bytes object
 |  
 |  Construct an immutable array of bytes from:
 |    - an iterable yielding integers in range(256)
 |    - a text string encoded using the specified encoding
 |    - any object implementing the buffer API.
 |    - an integer
```

In this case, `[10]` is used to invoke the `bytes(iterable_of_ints)` behavior rather than the `bytes(int)` behavior, despite only representing one byte.